# How can use routerLink and (click) in same button?

Tags: angular

i code sideNavBar and when i click on one icon i have two action. first my sideNavBar must open and second i must route to desired URL without reload browser, but when i use two these thing at same time , it just like my page reload and route to that URL, but when my html file render all other URL that i use alone work fine.

here is my code :

```
 <li class="li-margin-icon">
    <a class="icon-calendar"
       routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="./analysis-overview"></a>
  </li>

<li class="li-margin-icon">
    <a class="icon-calendar"
       (click)="subSideNav('content-production')"
       routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="./content/production"
       ></a>
  </li>
```

first router works fine but second one reload my browser for navigating to URL.

how can i fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

> You can move your routing code inside `ts` under function `subSideNav` -

### html

```
<li class="li-margin-icon">
    <a class="icon-calendar"
       (click)="subSideNav('content-production')"
       routerLinkActive="active"></a>
  </li>
```

### ts

```
  import { Router } from '@angular/router';

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  subSideNav(){
    //other code        
      this.router.navigate(['./content/production']);
  }
```